# How to change List Item value on WHEN_VALIDATE_ITEM

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am working on Forms 6i on a very old software.
There is a requirement to add 3 List Item (Combo Box) to the form.
If the value in List Item X is changed, then upon `WHEN_VALIDATE_ITEM`, I need to change the value on List Item Y.
Here is the code but it's not working.

```
BEGIN
IF  :PIH.TEXT_ITEM1544='Book' THEN
Copy('Own Use',Name_In('PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546'));
END IF;
END;
```

There are no errors in compilation, but I believe that when I select the value Book and press enter or tab and go to another field, nothing is triggered.

Any help would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do exactly? If you want to assign the value `'Own Use'` to the item `PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546` you can do it with:

```
:PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546 := 'Own Use';
```

Or with:

```
Copy('Own Use','PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546')
```

The statement you're using:

```
Copy('Own Use',Name_In('PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546'));
```

is trying to copy the value `'Own Use'` to the item referenced by `PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546`, i.e., it's trying to copy the value to an item named as the value stored in the item `PIH.TEXT_ITEM1546`.

The `Name_In` function gets the value of the specified item.